# Adapt von Mises KDE to Seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, seaborn, kernel-density

I am attempting to use Seaborn to plot a bivariate (joint) KDE on a polar projection. There is no support for this in Seaborn, and no direct support for an angular (von Mises) KDE in Scipy.

[scipy gaussian_kde and circular data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44783738) solves a related but different case. Similarities are - random variable is defined over linearly spaced angles on the unit circle; the KDE is plotted. Differences: I want to use Seaborn's [joint kernel density estimate support](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/joint_kde.html) to produce a contour plot of this kind -

[image: contour joint KDE]

but with no categorical ("species") variation, and on a polar projection. The marginal plots would be nice-to-have but are not important.

The rectilinear version of my situation would be

```py
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from numpy.random._generator import default_rng

angle = np.repeat(
    np.deg2rad(
        np.arange(0, 360, 10)
    ),
    100,
)
rand = default_rng(seed=0)
data = pd.Series(
    rand.normal(loc=50, scale=10, size=angle.size),
    index=pd.Index(angle, name='angle'),
    name='power',
)

matplotlib.use(backend='TkAgg')
joint = sns.JointGrid(
    data.reset_index(),
    x='angle', y='power'
)
joint.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, bw_adjust=0.7, linewidths=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: rectilinear]

but this is shown in the wrong projection, and also there should be no decreasing contour lines between the angles of 0 and 360.

Of course, as [Creating a circular density plot using matplotlib and seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62197982) explains, the naive approach of using the existing Gaussian KDE in a polar projection is not valid, and even if I wanted to I couldn't, because `axisgrid.py` hard-codes the subplot setup with no parameters:

```py
        f = plt.figure(figsize=(height, height))
        gs = plt.GridSpec(ratio + 1, ratio + 1)

        ax_joint = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, :-1])
        ax_marg_x = f.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1], sharex=ax_joint)
        ax_marg_y = f.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1], sharey=ax_joint)
```

I started in with a monkeypatching approach:

```py
import scipy.stats._kde
import numpy as np


def von_mises_estimate(
    points: np.ndarray,
    values: np.ndarray,
    xi: np.ndarray,
    cho_cov: np.ndarray,
    dtype: np.dtype,
    real: int = 0
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Mimics the signature of gaussian_kernel_estimate
    https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/_stats.pyx#L740
    """

    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44783738
    # Will make this a parameter
    kappa = 20

    # I am unclear on how 'values' would be used here


class VonMisesKDE(scipy.stats._kde.gaussian_kde):
    def __call__(self, points: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        points = np.atleast_2d(points)

        result = von_mises_estimate(
            self.dataset.T,
            self.weights[:, None],
            points.T,
            self.inv_cov,
            points.dtype,
        )
        return result[:, 0]


import seaborn._statistics
seaborn._statistics.gaussian_kde = VonMisesKDE
```

and this does successfully get called in place of the default Gaussian function, but (1) it's incomplete, and (2) I'm not clear that it would be possible to convince the joint plot methods to use the new projection.

A very distorted and low-quality preview of what this would look like, via Gimp transformation:

[image: gimp transformation]

though the radial axis would increase instead of decrease from the centre out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea for an approach:

- convert the polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates via `sin` and `cos`
- use these to generate a normal `jointplot` (or `kdeplot`, this can include `hue`)
- hide the axes of the Cartesian plot
- to add the polar aspect: create a dummy polar plot on top and rescale it appropriately
- the kdeplots for the angles and the powers can be added manually
- to enable wrap-around for the angles, just copy the angles shifted by -360 and +360 degrees and afterward limit the displayed range

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# test data from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/muthuj7/weather-dataset
df = pd.read_csv('weatherhistory.csv')[['Wind Speed (km/h)', 'Wind Bearing (degrees)']].rename(
    columns={'Wind Bearing (degrees)': 'angle', 'Wind Speed (km/h)': 'power'})
df['angle'] = np.radians(df['angle'])

df['x'] = df['power'] * np.cos(df['angle'])
df['y'] = df['power'] * np.sin(df['angle'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
grid_ratio = 5
gs = plt.GridSpec(grid_ratio + 1, grid_ratio + 1)

ax_joint = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, :-1])
ax_marg_x = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1])
ax_marg_y = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1])

sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', bw_adjust=0.7, linewidths=1, ax=ax_joint)

ax_joint.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')  # equal aspect ratio is needed for a polar plot
ax_joint.axis('off')
xmin, xmax = ax_joint.get_xlim()
xrange = max(-xmin, xmax)
ax_joint.set_xlim(-xrange, xrange)  # force 0 at center
ymin, ymax = ax_joint.get_ylim()
yrange = max(-ymin, ymax)
ax_joint.set_ylim(-yrange, yrange)  # force 0 at center

ax_polar = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
ax_polar.set_facecolor('none')  # make transparent
ax_polar.set_position(pos=ax_joint.get_position())
ax_polar.set_rlim(0, max(xrange, yrange))

# add kdeplot of power as marginal y
sns.kdeplot(y=df['power'], ax=ax_marg_y)
ax_marg_y.set_ylim(0, df['power'].max() * 1.1)
ax_marg_y.set_xlabel('')
ax_marg_y.set_ylabel('')
ax_marg_y.text(1, 0.5, 'power', transform=ax_marg_y.transAxes, ha='center', va='center')
sns.despine(ax=ax_marg_y, bottom=True)

# add kdeplot of angles as marginal x, repeat the angles shifted -360 and 360 degrees to enable wrap-around
angles = np.degrees(df['angle'])
angles_trippled = np.concatenate([angles - 360, angles, angles + 360])
sns.kdeplot(x=angles_trippled, ax=ax_marg_x)
ax_marg_x.set_xlim(0, 360)
ax_marg_x.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 361, 45))
ax_marg_x.set_xlabel('')
ax_marg_x.set_ylabel('')
ax_marg_x.text(0.5, 1, 'angle', transform=ax_marg_x.transAxes, ha='center', va='center')
sns.despine(ax=ax_marg_x, left=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: polar version of sns.jointplot]

PS: This is how a filled version could look like (with `cmap='turbo'`):

[image: filled polar kdeplot]

If you want 0 at the top, and let the angle go around clockwise, you need to switch `x=` and `y=` in the call to the 2D `kdeplot`.

```
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='y', y='x', bw_adjust=0.7, fill=True, cmap='turbo', ax=ax_joint)

# ....
ax_polar = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
ax_polar.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax_polar.set_theta_direction('clockwise')
```

Comment: Quite interesting. The marginals aren't particularly valid, since true polar marginals should correspond to the entire circumference and the radius, respectively.

Comment: You didn't specify which kind of marginal plots you wanted.  I updated the plot with marginal kdeplots of the angles and the radii.  As the kdeplot of constant angles is a rather flat line, I downloaded some test data from kaggle.  Note that creating the 2D kdeplot for 380K points is rather slow with seaborn.

Comment: Overall this is an excellent trick and I've successfully implemented it in my analysis. I appreciate you updating the marginals, but I just ended up hiding mine. I also had to decrease the Z-order of the polar axes.

Comment: This is clever but seems a little bit wrong to me ... why should the estimate for the density of "low power with angle 0" be an average of observations that include "medium power with angle 0" and "low power with angle 180"?

Comment: @mwaskom  I agree that the solution won't fit all situations. For wind direction and speed, it probably makes some sense.   Non-Gaussian kdes, especially in more than one dimension, seem quite complicated and in need of many parameters to suit specific situations.  Regular kdeplots are often used for variables that can't be negative, but that doesn't mean they aren't useful in comparing distributions (as long as the viewer is aware of the limitations).

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past by using a combination of `seaborn` and `matplotlib`'s polar projection. Here is an example (using `seaborn` version 0.12.0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

n_data = 1000
data_phase = np.random.rand(n_data) * 1.2 * np.pi
data_amp = np.random.randn(n_data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.scatter(data_phase, data_amp, vmin=0, vmax=2 * np.pi, s=10, alpha=0.3)
ax.set_thetagrids(angles=np.linspace(0, 360, 5));
sns.kdeplot(x=data_phase, y=data_amp, n_levels=5, c='k', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Hope you're able to adapt it to your needs from there?

Comment: How does `kdeplot` know to use the same set of axes as `scatter`?

Comment: Oh sorry; edited it. In this case it worked because it was the only axis present. But you can specify `ax` as arg in `kdeplot()`

Comment: Your code also produces the warning _No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'vmin', 'vmax' will be ignored_

Comment: Right, not sure why. You can leave out the `c` argument, but then the lines are the default colour (eg blue).

Comment: As the warning says: your `vmin` and `vmax` have no effect. You can delete them and keep `c`

Comment: Oh I get a different warning: *"The following kwargs were not used by contour: 'c'"*
I'm on `sns` version 0.12.0, `matplotlib` 3.5.2

Comment: OK. Anyway, this is a piece of the puzzle; it doesn't address the fact that `kdeplot` is hard-coded to use a Gaussian kernel

Comment: Oh ok. As I understood your question you had already implemented this? Couldn't you reset `sns` kde as you did, and then plot as I suggested?

Comment: Refer to `I am unclear on how 'values' would be used here` - I don't know how that inner bit would be done

Comment: I have tried this but it says "TypeError: kdeplot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'"

Comment: @MatthewWatson you shouldn't need `data` if you specifiy `x` and `y` args. I've added my `seaborn` version to the answer (0.12.0). Are you able to reproduce the code in my reply?